# Is it possible to keep data in procedure Raid1 growing to Raid5?

Tags: raid, raid5, raid0

I have Raid 1

`/dev/sda` `/dev/sdb`

as `md0`

then now I want to expand for Raid5

So, my idea is

```
sudo mdadm --add /dev/md0 /dev/sdd

sudo mdadm --grow /dev/md0 --level=raid5 --raid-devices=3
```

In these processes.

The contents in the HDD will be deleted or not??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's perfectly possible, and can be done even on a live system.

**IMPORTANT NOTE**: your data won't survive a disk failure during the conversion process, so make sure you have a backup.

Here's a demonstration using some files.

```
# Two "disks", probably called /dev/loop0 ($a) and /dev/loop1 ($b)
dd bs=1M count=100 </dev/zero >/tmp/img.a
a=$(losetup --show --find /tmp/img.a)

dd bs=1M count=100 </dev/zero >/tmp/img.b
b=$(losetup --show --find /tmp/img.b)

# Create RAID 1
mdadm --create /dev/md0 --metadata=1.2 --level=raid1 --raid-devices=2 $a $b

# See what is going on
cat /proc/mdstat

# Add a filesystem and mount it
mkfs -t ext4 -L md /dev/md0

mkdir -p /mnt/dsk
mount /dev/md0 /mnt/dsk
```

Now we'll grow the disk array

```
# Another disk, probably /dev/loop2 ($d)
dd bs=1M count=100 </dev/zero >/tmp/img.d
d=$(losetup --show --find /tmp/img.d)

# Add it as a spare
mdadm --add /dev/md0 $d

# Convert from RAID 1 to RAID 5
mdadm --grow /dev/md0 --level=raid5 --raid-devices=3

# See what is going on
cat /proc/mdstat
```

When you have confirmed to yourself that the process is indeed safe, you can repeat the process with your real disks. Do you have a backup?

```
a=/dev/sda b=/dev/sdb` d=/dev/sdd
```

Answer (score 2):

Growing RAID1 to RAID5 works fine, (but you should still have backups just in case.)

> `sudo mdadm --add /dev/md0 /dev/sdd`

This command would add `/dev/sdd` to your `/dev/md0` RAID1 as a spare drive.

Other than `mdadm` metadata, nothing will be written to it (unless one of the other drives failed, so the spare would be used to restore redundancy).

> `sudo mdadm --grow /dev/md0 --level=raid5 --raid-devices=3`

This command would grow your 2-disk RAID1 to a 3-disk RAID5. This process reshapes / relocates all data (from previous 2-drive mirror to 3-drive RAID5 layout). During this process, whatever was on `/dev/sdd` before will be overwritten by contents of `/dev/md0`. Data on device `/dev/md0` won't change at all except for additional capacity once growing is done. You'll have to grow the filesystem to utilize the added capacity.

You can combine both commands into one:

```
mdadm --grow /dev/md0 --level=5 --raid-devices=3 --add /dev/sdd
```

---

In general, `--grow` is supposed to be safe and retain data. `mdadm` should warn you when trying to do dangerous operations (such as shrinking) or when additional steps are necessary (such as providing a backup file).

You lose data when you `--create` (like `mkfs`), or when too many drives `--fail`, or when messing with the member drives in other ways.

You'll also lose whatever is on `/dev/sdd` since you're growing your RAID with it, so `/dev/sdd` gets overwritten with whatever currently is on `/dev/md0`.

If `--grow` lost data, there would be no point in using it at all, you'd just `--create` a new one in the first place.